# Import-Export Call Order in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

This is a "code theory" question.

So imagine this scenario, I am using the global namespace in a package. I have a main entrypoint file, some class files that I export, and some utility files the classes use. Here's a theoretical file structure:

```
/index.js (main entrypoint)  
/src  
|_/source.js (exporting function for src folder)  
|_/utils  
  |_/headers.js
  |_/constants.js
|_/classes
  |_/class1.js
  |_/class2.js
```

In constants.js I define some global variables and then export an object that uses some global variables.
*/src/utils/constants.js*

```js
const foobar = 'foo';
global.foobar = foobar;

export default {
  foo: global.foobar,
}
```

In some class file I import constants.js.
*/src/classes/class1.js*

```js
import constants from '../utils/constants.js'

export default class Xyzzy {
  function baz() {
    return constants.foo + 'baz'
  }
}
```

And finally in the entrypoint file I import `source.js` which imports `/src/classes/class1` and `/src/classes/class2` and exports both of them, then define some global variables.
*/index.js*

```js
import source from '/src/source.js'

export default function index() {
  global.foobar = 'bar'
  
  return {
    class1: source.class1,
    class2: source.class2,
  }
}
```

What would be the assignment order of global.foobar, what is the final result, and most importantly **why does this happen**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/:

> When you run a module containing an import declaration, the modules it imports are loaded first, then each module body is executed in a depth-first traversal of the dependency graph, avoiding cycles by skipping anything already executed.

So in your case:

1. The entry point module *index.js* is loaded, and depends on *source.js*
2. The *source.js* module is loaded, and depends on *class1.js* and *class2.js*
3. The *class1.js* module is loaded, and depends on *constants.js*
4. The *constants.js* module is loaded, and depends on nothing, so it is evaluted. This assigns `'foo'` to the `foobar` variable.
5. Now that the dependencies of *class1.js* are satisfied, it is executed.
6. (Assuming *class2.js* looks similar to *class1.js*), the *class2.js* module is laoded, and depends on *constants.js*. This is already initialised, so *class2.js* is executed.
7. Now that the dependencies of *source.js* are satisfied, it is executed.
8. Now that the dependencies of *index.js* are satisfied, it is executed. This assigns `'bar'` to the `foobar` variable.

Of course, the entire purpose of modules is that you should need to reason about this, when you don't use global variables :-)

Comment: Wow thanks for the in-depth explanation. This really helped!

Answer (score 1):

`import` declaration works like *require-once* or *lazy-require*. A module is evaluated once it is imported: further imports won't evaluate it again.

So, in regards to how `foobar` mutates, according to your imports, the following should happen, in order:

- 1. `src/utils/constants.js` sets `global.foobar = 'foo'`
- 2. `index.js` sets `global.foobar = 'bar'`

The entry code does nothing, it only exports a function as a property `default`.

Comment: I would disagree because the entrypoint sets the global variable, not src/source.js.

Comment: @RayhanADev Ah, I mistaken `source.js` as the entrypoint. I meant `index.js` instead of `src/source.js`